# Title: Bootstrap Carousel - Centered Card with Unique Height Transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, carousel, bootstrap-5

#### Description:

I'm working on a Bootstrap Carousel that displays five cards on medium screens. I want to achieve a unique style for the centered card with a slightly bigger height than the other cards. Additionally, I'd like to add a CSS transition to smoothly animate the height change of the centered card whenever the carousel slides to a new item.

#### Current Implementation:

I have successfully implemented a Bootstrap Carousel with five cards displayed on the medium screen using the **col-md-2.4** class. The carousel is working correctly, and I'm able to slide through the cards using the next and previous buttons.

#### The Challenge:

Now, I need to dynamically adjust the height of the centered card so that it appears taller than the other cards. I would like the centered card to change based on the currently active slide as the user clicks the next or previous button.

#### Attempted Solution:

I tried using the following JavaScript code to calculate the tallest card's height among the visible cards and set the height of the centered card accordingly:

```
var carousel = document.getElementById("recipeCarousel");
carousel.addEventListener("slid.bs.carousel", function () {
  var activeSlide = carousel.querySelector(".carousel-item.active");
  var cards = activeSlide.querySelectorAll(".card");
  var tallestCardHeight = 400;
  cards.forEach(function (card, index) {
    if (index === 2) {
      card.style.height = tallestCardHeight + "px";
    } else {
      var cardHeight = card.offsetHeight;
      if (cardHeight > tallestCardHeight) {
        tallestCardHeight = cardHeight;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

#### The Issue:

Although the JavaScript logic appears correct, I'm facing difficulty in achieving the desired height adjustment for the centered card. The height changes are not being smoothly animated with the CSS transition.

[image]

#### Desired Outcome:

I am seeking guidance on how to correctly apply the CSS transition to the height change of the centered card when the carousel slides to a new item. I want the height transition to be smooth and visually appealing for the user.

Any help, suggestions, or insights on how to achieve this effect would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

#### Code Samples:

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel .carousel-item')

items.forEach((el) => {
    const minPerSlide = 5
    let next = el.nextElementSibling
    for (var i = 1; i < minPerSlide; i++) {
        if (!next) {
            // wrap carousel by using first child
            next = items[0]
        }
        let cloneChild = next.cloneNode(true)
        el.appendChild(cloneChild.children[0])
        next = next.nextElementSibling
    }
})

var carousel = document.getElementById("recipeCarousel");
carousel.addEventListener("slid.bs.carousel", function () {
    var activeSlide = carousel.querySelector(".carousel-item.active");
    var cards = activeSlide.querySelectorAll(".card");
    var tallestCardHeight = 400;
    cards.forEach(function (card, index) {
        if (index === 2) {
            // Set the height of the card with index 2 to the height of the tallest card
            card.style.height = tallestCardHeight + "px";
            // card.classList.add('centered-card')
        } else {
            // Get the height of the card and compare it to the tallest card
            var cardHeight = card.offsetHeight;
            if (cardHeight > tallestCardHeight) {
                tallestCardHeight = cardHeight;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div {
      display: none;
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div:first-child {
      display: block;
  }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

/* medium and up screens */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-end.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
    transform: translateX(20%);
  }
  
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-start.active, 
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    transform: translateX(-20%);
  }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-end,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-start { 
transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link href="./test.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="container text-center my-3">
    <h2 class="font-weight-light">Bootstrap Multi Slide Carousel</h2>
    <div class="row mx-auto my-auto justify-content-center">
        <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="col-md-2.4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x400/31f?text=1" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 1</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-2.4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x400/e66?text=2" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 2</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-2.4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x400/7d2?text=3" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 3</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-2.4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x400?text=4" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 4</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-2.4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x400/aba?text=5" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 5</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-2.4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x400/fc0?text=6" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 6</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev bg-transparent w-aut" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next bg-transparent w-aut" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h5 class="mt-2 fw-light">advances one slide at a time</h5>
  </div>

</div>
  



  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```